# aws eb cli Windows get version error on colorama

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have installed awsebcli in windows 10

It was showing

```
2.2,!=2.18.0,<2.19,>=2.6.1->docker-compose<1.22.0,>=1.21.2->awsebcli) (1.22)
docker-compose 1.21.2 has requirement colorama<0.4,>=0.3.9; sys_platform == "win32", but you'll have colorama 0.3.7 which is incompatible.
```

Now when I was trying to do

eb --version I got error

```
 raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (colorama 0.3.7 (c:\users\rajarshi.das\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages), Requirement.parse('colorama<0.4,>=0.3.9; sys_platform == "win32"'), {'docker-compose'})
```

I was trying to remove the colorama and install 0.3.9 version now it was showing eb is required 0.3.7 version only...

Please help.

Comment: I have the same problem - happened after I upgrade PIP 9.01 to 10.0.0, but didn't fix after I downgraded

Comment: Problem appears to be that docker-compose requires colorama v 0.3.9 while awsebcli requires 0.3.7

Comment: any update how can I use it

Comment: @PrettyCool, @RJD, you should be able to use the package despite the version mismatch, although it appears that you are not. Can you try `eb --version` after  `pip uninstall -y awsebcli; pip install awsebcli`? If not, for now, rolling back to 3.13.0 might be the better option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got the same issue.

like dakshina11 said

> pip install 'awsebcli==3.13.0' --upgrade --user

the older version of awsebcli==3.13.0 solved this problem.

Currently 3.14.0 still not working.